# sending mail after payment paypal contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, email, paypal, contact-form-7

I have a form with contact form 7 in a WordPress site. 
When you click on "submit" you are redirected on Paypal and pleased to pay :). Everything works well, but the I want something more. 
I want to send the mail, ONLY when visitors have pay on Paypal.
I've searched on google, but I don't have found the way to do this.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to get this done.  There is a [free plugin available to get PayPal IPN setup in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) very easily, but then you'll need to make a basic hook from your functions.php file (or your own plugin) to trigger the email based on when you want it sent.

You can trigger any action you want based on different PayPal transaction types or payment status.

Here is a very basic example of sending an email from an extension to the IPN plugin.  This is a full plugin file with nothing but a hook to the plugin.  In this case I'm using the **paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_txn_type_cart** hook.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package PayPal IPN for WordPress - Hook Template
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: PayPal IPN for WordPress - Hook Template
Plugin URI: http://www.angelleye.com/
Description: Hook tester for PayPal IPN for WordPress plugin.
Author: angelleye
Version: 1.0.0
*/


add_action('paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_txn_type_cart', 'paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_txn_type_cart', 10, 1);
function paypal_ipn_for_wordpress_txn_type_cart($posted) {

    // Parse data from IPN $posted array

    $payment_status = isset($posted['payment_status']) ? $posted['payment_status'] : '';
    $mc_gross = isset($posted['mc_gross']) ? $posted['mc_gross'] : '';
    $first_name = isset($posted['first_name']) ? $posted['first_name'] : '';
    $last_name = isset($posted['last_name']) ? $posted['last_name'] : '';
    $cart_items = isset($posted['cart_items']) ? $posted['cart_items'] : '';

    /**
     * At this point you can use the data to generate email notifications,
     * update your local database, hit 3rd party web services, or anything
     * else you might want to automate based on this type of IPN.
     */
    $to = 'email@domain.com';
    $subject = 'Email from PayPal IPN';
    $message = 'Order Total: ' . $mc_gross . "\n";
    $message .= 'Payment Status: ' . $payment_status . "\n";
    $message .= 'Name: ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . "\n";
    $message .= 'Cart Items: ' . print_r($cart_items, true);
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

So with both the IPN plugin and this plugin installed on your site, any time a cart transaction is made on your PayPal account an email would be sent accordingly. This is a sample of the email I received when running a test transaction on PayPal with this plugin activated on the site.

```
Order Total: 90.27
Payment Status: Completed
Name: Tester Testerson
Cart Items: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_number] =>
            [item_name] => Woo Album #2
            [quantity] => 1
            [mc_gross] => 75.27
            [mc_handling] => 0.00
            [mc_shipping] => 0.00
            [custom] =>
            [option_name1] =>
            [option_selection1] =>
            [option_name2] =>
            [option_selection2] =>
            [btn_id] =>
            [tax] => 0.00
        )

)
```

Of course, you could spend the time to make the email more pretty and send it to any email address(es) you need to.

So again, you can use [lots of different hooks](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ipn-wordpress-hooks/) to trigger your own plugin functions like this based on different IPN types or payment status.

The sample here only includes a few data parameters that IPN provides, but the IPN record in WordPress will give you a template you can easily copy/paste into your own plugin file that includes every IPN parameter available to that type of IPN.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have install the plugin, and I have understand what it does ! But I have to understand how to do the hook between Contact Form 7 and Paypal IPN, and that's can be hard.

Comment: You wouldn't really be hooking between those 2 plugins.  Contact Form 7 (or any method of processing a PayPal payment) will send the payment to PayPal.  PayPal's server would then trigger the IPN to be sent to the URL you configure with the plugin.  Then you would add a hook into the IPN plugin alone to trigger your own events based on when IPNs hit that URL.  I'm going to put together a tutorial for this before long, but it might be a few days before I get that done.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explain, it looks easy when you talking about this, but in reality ... LOL. I've to search

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: I just updated the answer with more details about how to get it done.  You can just copy/paste what's there and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if I understand well.
In my case, I have a form created with contact form 7 plugin, in wich one I have all the customers data I want to collect.
The contact form 7 plugin sends the mail with the informations just after you click on "Submit".
But, I have redirected the submit button, if you choose value 1, you are redirected on an object paypal, if you choose value 2 on another object paypal.
I just have to collect the paypal payment status before the email has been sent and only after authorize contact form 7 to send the form by email.
Sorry for this long speech ...

Comment: Ok, what I'm explaining would be generating your own custom emails from within the IPN extension.  I didn't realize you already had emails but just needed the status.  You could get it accomplished with the steps I mentioned, and it wouldn't take long, but that may not be what you're after.  I was thinking that the form would submit the payment to PayPal with all the data, and then PayPal sends that data to your IPN listener, so within that you can do whatever you want with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Listed [PayPal IPN plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) is not available at the time, is any other active plugins instead?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.